# R wildcards, sapply and as.factor

Tags: r, sapply

I want to change the type to factor of all variables in a data frame whose names match a certain pattern.

So here I am trying to change the type to factor of all variables whose name begins with *namestub* in the dataframe `df`.

```
attach(df)    
sapply(grep(glob2rx("namestub*"), names(df)), as.factor)
```

But this doesn't work since

```
> levels(df$namestub1)
NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
## Make a reproducible example
df <- data.frame(namestubA = letters[1:5], B = letters[5:1], 
                 namestubC = LETTERS[1:5], stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

## Get indices of columns to convert
ii <- grep(glob2rx("namestub*"), names(df))

## Convert and replace the indicated columns
df[ii] <- lapply(df[ii], as.factor)
```

Comment: Thanks Josh! So if I wanted to change the levels of all the grepped variables in one go, then could I do `levels(df[ii])<- c("a", "b", "c")`?

Comment: Nope, that's also a bit mixed up.  I'd suggest having a separate look at the objects returned by the left hand side and right hand side of my last line of code (using `str()`, `is()`, `length()`, etc.), then reading up on `?lapply`. Assignment of new levels (with `levels<-`) needs to be done to one vector/column at a time, perhaps by wrapping it too in a call to `lapply()` and then assigning the results back into `df`.

Comment: Great. Realised `ii` is a vector, hence used the following loop: `for(i in seq(along=ii)) { levels(df[,ii[i]]) <- c("a", "b", "c")}`. Wish there were a non-loop way of doing this.

Comment: Or just `for(i in ii) levels(df[,i]) <-` on the left. IMHO, There's really nothing wrong with a loop here, and the code actually ends up cleaner than what using `lapply()` would require.

Comment: If you wanted to set the levels cleanly with `lapply`: `df[ii] <- lapply(df[ii], factors, labels = levels)`